# How to use token based authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: android, django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I want to implement token based authentication in my application that uses Django Rest Framework and a Android client.

The way this works, [as far as I understand](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#ConnectToService), is I need to send the `client ID` and the `client secret` to the API end point together with the `access token`.

The `access token` [is gotten from the Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens) as so:

```
Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I have a few question that I'd like to clarify to glue all of this together.

1. How do I handle the `client ID` and the `client secret` in Django Rest Framework?
2. How do I store the `client ID` and the `client secret` in Android? I can't simply store them as a String. Someone could find the string literal in the APK.

Comment: If you insist using oauth2 - you best choice would be to use this app on server side - https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Comment: @mariodev. Thanks but I don't intend to use passwords. I intend to simply use a unique token generated by the server: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication but in your suggested library, it seems that it requires a password,username no?

Comment: You don't have to - please read more about how oauth2 works (you can simply choose different grant type, the example assumes it's password)

Comment: @mariodev, I read this [explanantion](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) and specially this [diagram](https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/oauth/abstract_flow.png). Therefore in my case, where I have an [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#RequestToken) on the Android client, REST endpoint, and no passwords i.e [only token authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), the first two steps are deleted (see the diagram)?

Comment: have you ever heard of djangorestframework-jwt?

Comment: No but thank you kindly.